# Can I set up a 'Deny from x' that overrides other confs for debugging?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm currently working on developing/deploying a Django application on Apache and am often fiddling with the debug settings which alter how Django accepts connections, ignoring or using `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.  If `DEBUG` is False, it uses them, which is handy to keep up some walls around my construction site.  However, the useful info it spits out when True is quite nice.

I'm currently just using an SSH tunnel and just allowing localhost when `DEBUG` is False, but how can I keep everyone out without relying on the aforementioned `ALLOWED_HOSTS`?  Editing the httpd.conf file which is in source control is a bit irritating; I've accidentally committed a few botched configs.

Answer (score 1):

Just use your firewall to allow access to port 80 only from your development workstation.